# How to fix this FFMPEG command to record audio as well?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to fix this FFMPEG command to record audio.

I have tried using the parts recommended on the official stackoverflow site but they didn't work

Orignal Command

`ffmpeg_stream = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -r 24 -i :%d+nomouse -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -threads 0 -f flv "%s"' % (xvfb.new_display, info['destination'])`

Command with attempted audio

`ffmpeg_stream = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -r 24 -i :%d+nomouse -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -threads 0 -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0 -f flv "%s"' % (xvfb.new_display, info['destination'])`

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg expects a specific arrangement in command line: all inputs first followed by outputs.

So,

`ffmpeg_stream = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 24 -i :%d+nomouse -f alsa -channels 2 -i hw:0 -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv "%s"' % (xvfb.new_display, info['destination']`